# using ffmpeg for mp3 to ogg conversion

Tags: php

Am new to php. With some of the reference to the posts on Stackoverflow, i've tried out the method to convert an mp3 audio file to ogg simultaneously while uploading to the server, initially i checked on my localhost, i always got an output int(1) in response for var_dump($output), but i cant see the ogg converted file saved anywhere in folder. Can any please guilde, its urgent. My questions are:

1) Do i need to provide path for both input and output files, if yes then, did i mention properly in code here.
2) where exactly i need to save/place the entire ffmpeg folder / ffmpeg.exe
3) Are all the path mentioned w.r.t the input and output file proper in code here ?

```
passthru("/admin/ffmpeg32/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i audioUpload/".$_FILES['audio_file']['name']." -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis -target ./ffmpeg32/ogg/$file_name".".ogg",$output);
var_dump($output);
```